# Flask - Not loading new page on browser

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to implement a simple data download with Flask. In this process, I would like Flask to change from a html page to another.

I've tried to use both render_template and redirect to change the html page both none of them have worked. What am I doing wrong?

```
def get_data():
    data = request.get_json() or request.form
    site = data['site']
    dataInicio = data['dataInicio']
    dataFim = data['dataFim']
    infos = [site, dataInicio, dataFim]
    df = get_dataframe(site, dataInicio, dataFim)
    filename = "{}_{}_{}.csv".format(site, dataInicio, dataFim).replace('/','-')
    df.to_csv(filename)
    print(os.getcwd())
    return redirect(url_for('download'))


@app.route('/download')
def download():
    filename = session.get('filename', None)
    return render_template('download.html', filename = filename)
```

No error is returned, the console log is:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2019 17:14:25] "POST /_get_data/ HTTP/1.1" 302 -
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Jan/2019 17:14:25] "GET /download HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

But the page `download.html` is not loaded in the browser.

Comment: are you getting any error messages?

Comment: i'm trying to understand your get_data function. For instance, what does this line do:     df = get_data(site, dataInicio, dataFim). Also, when you redirect to download, you call session for filename. I wonder if this will return any value.

Comment: Not sure how this code will work, your get_data function isn't mapped to a route. You only have the download route defined. What is your exact goal and I can help you from there?

Comment: Sorry, the code I posted was a little bit wrong, the line `df = get_data()` is actually `df = get_dataframe()` and it calls a function that returns a pandas dataframe. Until here everything works fine. I'm edditing the post to add the console log and fix the line above.

Comment: Looking at your download route, the filename = session.get.. where is this session set in the first place? If you want a file to be downloaded, you can do something like this return send_file(filename, attachment_filename='filename.txt', as_attachment=True).